# Unity 2020.3.xx Gradle build failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, gradle

I've been working some android unity project but when i try to build i got some Errors
Here is one;

**Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 stopped Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :launcher
> WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
> It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
> You will no longer be able to disable R8

Build-tool 31.0.0 is missing DX at /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/31.0.0/dx

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)**

Then this one;

** Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

> Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 stopped Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :launcher
> WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
> It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
> You will no longer be able to disable R8

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <caed2e60415e48d1850197a030a83f5f>:0) UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at :0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at :0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at :0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:337)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU6wX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTWR9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmglE.png)

Comment: You should focus your question in a specific problem, just put a bunch of logs doesn't help to understand your problem.

Comment: You could try to download the External Dependency manager asset https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure, but last time I had a Gradle build failure for Android, I needed to Update Unity Hub and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, and it solves it by installing the android studio SDKs and in the folders where the SDKs are, enter "build-tools" and delete those that were more than 30 and it was solved
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auCVh.png)